# C++ intel TBB inner loop optimisation

Tags: c++, c++11, parallel-processing, tbb, parallel.for

I am trying to use Intel TBB to parallelise  an inner loop (the 2nd of 3) however, i only get decent pay off when the inner 2 loops are significant in size.

Is TBB spawning new threads for every iteration of the major loop?
Is there anyway to reduce the overhead?

```
tbb::task_scheduler_init tbb_init(4); //I have 4 cores
tbb::blocked_range<size_t> blk_rng(0, crs_.y_sz, crs_.y_sz/4);
boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point start   =boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
for(unsigned i=0; i!=5000; ++i)
{   
    tbb::parallel_for(blk_rng, 
    [&](const tbb::blocked_range<size_t>& br)->void
    {   
    :::
```

It might be interesting to note that openMP (which I am trying to remove!!!) doesn't have this problem.

I am compiling with:

intel ICC 12.1 at -03 -xHost -mavx

On a intel 2500k (4 cores)

EDIT: I can really change the order of loops, because the out loops test need to be replace with a predicate based on the loops result.

Comment: It appears you're asking it to spawn a parallel piece of work 5000 times, is that accurate?

Comment: @sixlettervariables yes, I get great gains with openMP, I want to know whether I can replicate such gains with TBB

Comment: try using the partitioners in tbb, particularly the affinity_partiioner if you haven't. OpenMP fixed partitioning is really good at small inner loops because of the policies it applies to thread teams...

Comment: @Rick I have take a look a partitioner, TBH they rarely show an improvement over setting the blocked_ranges step to size/num_threads

Answer (score 1):

No, TBB does not spawn new threads for every invocation of `parallel_for`. Actually, unlike OpenMP parallel regions that each may start a new thread team, TBB work with the same thread team until all `task_scheduler_init` objects are destroyed; and in case of implicit initialization (with `task_scheduler_init` omitted), same worker threads are used till the end of the program.

So the performance issue is caused by something else. The most likely reasons, from my experience, are:

- lack of compiler optimizations, auto-vectorization being first (can be checked by comparing single-threaded performance of OpenMP and TBB; if TBB is much slower, then this is the most likely reason).
- cache misses; if you 5000 times run through the same data, cache locality has huge importance, and OpenMP's default `schedule(static)` works very well, deterministically repeating exactly the same partitioning each time, while TBB's work stealing scheduler has significant randomness. Setting the blocked_range grain size equal to problem_size/num_threads ensures one piece of work per thread but does not guarantee the same distribution of pieces; and `affinity_partitioner` is supposed to help with that.